# ListView IsTextSearchEnabled="False" not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I wonder if anyone can shed some light on this for me.
I have a multicolumn ListView bound to an ObservableCollection. The last column is a TextBox (via DataTemplate).
Typing in the textbox is all fine UNTIL I type a character that matches one of the rows. At that point TextSearch kicks in, taking me out of my textbox and selecting the matched row.
To avoid this, I set **IsTextSearchEnabled="False"** on my ListView, however it doesn't work. TextSearch always kicks in if I type a character matching one of the rows of data.

This is driving me nuts!

Comment: You might share your code with us. Im quite bad at randomly guessing in the dark ;)

Comment: What you described shouldn't happen. but we will need more info to help you out. maybe include code and images so that we can clearly understand what's going on.